# What is the climate on Qo'noS like?

Tags: star-trek

Due to the current heat wave in Germany, I'm wondering what the climate on Qo'noS is like.

How likely is it that it's currently cooler in the capital of Qo'nos ("First City") than in Berlin (current temperature 37 °C = 99 °F)?

Comment: Due you mean before or after its moon exploded?

Comment: My temperature is roughly 37 °C.  It's probably similar on the main world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the original [script notes](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/165.txt) from TNG: Sins of the Father, we learn that the Klingon homeworld enjoys a harsh and highly variable climate due to its extreme axial tilt. This is later exacerbated by the destruction of its moon; Praxis.

> **EXT. SPACE - THE ENTERPRISE AND KLINGON HOME WORLD (OPTICAL)**
>   *The ship enters orbit. The planet has a single large land mass, and the world is dominated by a vast ocean. The tilt of the planet's axis
>   has created wild seasonal changes and the atmosphere should appear
>   turbulent and showing extremes of both warm and frigid weather of the
>   planet.*

Since their seasons are almost certainly out of phase with Earth's, it's impossible to tell what the weather is like *right now* other than to say "probably quite unpleasant".

Comment: Richard - you seem to have confused real time and fictional story time with "This is later exacerbated by the destruction of its moon, Praxis".  That is the same mistake responsible for the big chronological problem with STAR TREK V: THE fINAL fRONTIER.  And Praxis is described as "a Klingon moon", a moon somewhere in the Klingon Empire, instead of as "a moon of Qo'noS".  If Praxis was a moon of Qo'noS all life on Qo'noS should have been instantly destroyed by the blast.

Comment: @M.A.Golding - You can see them in the same picture here;  http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/8/8b/Kronos_2259.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/640?cb=20140315231239&path-prefix=en. I don't dispute you on the "real world" physics involved, but in the story it's a moon of the planet Kronos.

Comment: @M.A.Golding I distinctly recall (although I don't have a quote to back it up) that Praxis was a moon of the Klingon homeword (i.e Qo'noS).  I agree that if a moon of a blast literally exploded, it should have an immediate impact to that planet, but since the details of the explosion are not really discussed, it is possible that it did not immediately kill everyone as discussed and gave the Klingon's enough time to repair the damage

Comment: @Richard That picture is hardly compelling proof for most of us as its from JJ's universe. I've always thought of Praxis as the moon of Qo'noS as well but I thought I'd just point out that many will find that picture less than convincing.

Comment: @David - You know what they say about shooting the messenger?